# How to Copy and Paste Vertex Coordinates?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, coordinates

I have two meshes that are almost identical to each other. Mesh 1 is a human head, and Mesh 2 is the same head but cut in half. (think no mirror modifier) Both have the same topology where it would be.

I decided I want to adjust a couple vertices on Mesh 1, then I want to copy the coordinates of the vertices (to be clear: not the whole mesh, just the vertices I decide to select) and paste (or transfer?) that coordinate info to the identical vertices of Mesh 2.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same position, you can select both objects and tab into edit mode.  With x-ray view it's possible to select both of the vertices and perform the operation on them at the same time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes but one's already edited and I'm looking to transfer the info.

Comment: Oh I see.  Well if it's a small thing, in the N panel you can get the exact coordinates for a selected vert, or the median coordinates for a group of verts, under Item.  Otherwise I'll do some thinking on that...